# How to create table and import data in mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql, csv, insert, python-import

I want to create a table in MYSQL with python and then import data from csv to that. my code to create the table is:

```
    sqlcmd="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PA_TEST_CREDITS(`Identifier` TINYTEXT,`Test_Name` TINYTEXT,`Test_Component_Code` TINYTEXT,`Test_Component` TINYTEXT,`Test_Score` TINYINT,`Course_Prefix` TINYTEXT,`Course_Number` TINYTEXT,`Course_Title` TINYTEXT,`EARN_CREDIT` TINYTEXT,`Earned_Credit_Flag` TINYINT)"
cursor.execute(sqlcmd)
rconn.commit()
```

This code creates my table. for importing data I have used this code:

```
import csv
with open('PA_TEST_CREDITS.csv') as csvfile:
    csv_data=csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csv_data:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PA_TEST_CREDITS(Identifier, Test Name, Test Component Code, Test Component, Test Score, Course Prefix, Course Number, Course Title,EARN_CREDIT,Earned Credit Flag) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", row)
```

The error is "Data truncated for column 'Test_score' at row 1".

It would be appreciated if you help me. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your  Tinytext is big enough to store the data from the csv file? tinytext can store up to 255 chars

Answer (score 0):

Try `row.split(“,”)` as the second parameter for your execute command, so you pass an array instead of a string, since it might be trying to use the same string for all your parameters, and when it reaches the first non-text column it fails.

Also consider that Tinyint is only able to hold values from -128 to 127 (if signed) or from 0 to 255 (if unsigned).

If you have greater values on that CSV for the column it is also going to get truncated.

If so, check out the right integer type you need according to the values you're going to be using here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html